# Echoing/outputting information that was added to an input field on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, output

I'm creating a checkout system. I have three parts to it:

1. Shipping info
2. Payment info
3. Order confirmation

I'm trying to figure out a way that when the customer enters their shipping information, that data can be echo'd out onto my order confirmation part, so they can confirm that is where they want it shipped to.

The way I designed my checkout system is that all three parts are on the same page. Only one part shows at once and the others are hidden until the customer would click 'Proceed to xxxx'. When they click that Proceed button, nothing is being sent. It is just taking the div and showing it and hiding the previous div. Nothing is sent until when the customer clicks Submit order on the confirmation div.

I validate the fields and assigned them to variables so I can post the shipping and product info into my db.

```
if($validation->passed()) {
    if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
        $fullname = trim( $_POST['customer_name'] );
        $streetline1 = trim( $_POST['streetline1'] );
        $streetline2 = trim( $_POST['streetline2'] );
        $city = trim( $_POST['city'] );
        $state = trim( $_POST['state'] );
        $zipcode = trim( $_POST['zipcode'] );
        $phone_number = trim( $_POST['phone_number'] );
        $email = ( $_POST['email'] );
        //etc...
```

**Shipping Information Section:**

```
<div class="shippinginfocontainer">
    <span class="summarytitle">
    <p>Enter Shipping Information</p>
    </span><br>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" name="fullname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline1">Street Line 1</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" name="streetline1" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->streetline1); ?>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="streetline2">Street Line 2</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" name="streetline2" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->streetline2); ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="paddingleft" for="city">City</label>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline" name="city" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->city); ?>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formleftcenter">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" name="state" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->state); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="Phone Number">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" name="Phone Number" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->phone_number); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formrightcenter">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" name="zipcode" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->zipcode); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="mediuminputbar" name="email" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->email); ?>" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <button class="checkoutbutton" id="button2">Proceed to Payment Information</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I won't add my payment part as it is irrelevant to this question.

Then this is the relevant part of the Confirmation part. I wasn't sure how to do this, so I just wrote in echo's to show what I am trying to do.

```
<div class="confirmshippinginfo">
    <p>Shipping to:</p>
    <p><?php echo $fullname; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $streetline1; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $streetline2; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $city . $state . $zipcode; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
<input class="widebutton" type="submit" value="Place Your Order">
```

Is there a way to do this with keeping this all on the same page? I really do not want to have multiple pages for this and I like the way I have all of this formatted. I just can't figure out this part.

Comment: Are you wanting to save the information in the DB prior to showing the confirmation page?  If so, look into [ajax](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/).

Comment: No, I am only wanting to send it once, after the order has been submitted.

Comment: So for the confirmation, you just want to hide the form, and show the input in an un-editable fashion?

Comment: Yes, correct. I have three seperate div sections for this and each time they customer clicks proceed, it hides the div they were on and shows the next one. When the customer gets to the last div (confirmation) I want the information they entered in for their shipping information to show in this field. Not edititable.

Comment: If you want to see how my system works to get a good illustration my website is buyfarbest.com . I commented out the validation to allow freely going between the divs.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use `AJAX` via `serialize()` of your form when you click a review button (as *Matthew Johnson* suggested). Second idea is something like this where you copy from one input to another, in a different part of your page. It would take a bit more work to set up than something like `AJAX` because you are basically duplicating a form. Using `.html()` inside a `div` or `span` placeholder would probably work too:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="copy-from" data-copy="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="this-elem" id="name" disabled />
```

**CSS**

```
.this-elem {
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".copy-from").keyup(function() {
         var ElemId = $(this).data('copy');
        $("#"+ElemId).val($(this).val());
     });
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/fh5kfhtm/4/

---

**EDIT: AJAX/PHP Solution**

```
<!-- This is the placeholder for the data after submission -->
<div id="final"></div>
<!-- FORM, well really simplified form -->
<form id="orderform" method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_form" />
    <input type="text" name="address" />
    <!--
    This triggers the ajax (you would use your 
    "Proceed to Order Confirmation" button)
    -->
    <div id="confirm">CONFIRM</div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ORDER" />
</form>
```

**new.php**
File name/path must match what's in the AJAX `url`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order_form'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
}?>
```

**jQuery AJAX**

```
<!-- GET THE LIBRARIES (YOU SHOULD ALREADY HAVE THEM) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#confirm").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    // This is where you need the right path to the new php file
                    url:'/path/to/new.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $("#orderform").serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#final").html(response);
                    }
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you think the best solution is ajax?

Comment: Yeah, because you can have your 2nd button that advances you to the last slide page  trigger the AJAX and load it into the last confirmation page. It would only load the data, not submit the form.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ajax is something I have not looked into at all yet. I heard it wasn't too hard to pick up. How would I start to even do this with Ajax? I'm sure if I saw some that was applied to what I was doing I could finish it and modify it.

Comment: Great, I would really appreciate that!

Comment: There you go. I updated it. The ajax is triggered by the CONFIRM button, not the submit button

Comment: You got it @Rasclatt, I was doing the same thing :)